# Extracting certain columns from multiple txt files and saving as new csv files?

Tags: r

I have around 100 txt files. I'm trying to extract certain columns from each file, and then save it as new csv files for each txt file. Also, I want to set the names as something like '(name of original txt file)_new.txt'.

So far I've been able to read all the files at once, but I'm not sure how to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
data_all=list.files(pattern='.*.txt')
data<-lapply(data_all,read.csv,header=TRUE,sep='\t',skip=9)
```

Comment: Which is that 'certain' columns? Is it fixed column number like 1st. 2nd for each txt file or you want to extract them by name like column named "abc" and "xyz" from each ?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use `fread`

```
library(data.table)
data_all=list.files(pattern='.*.txt')

read.certain <- function(x, certain= certain_cols){fread(x), select = certain}
dat <- lapply(data_all,read.certain)
```

Comment: Can you add how to write the result to individual files?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this.

```
# Merge all CSV files into a single dataframe
# Set the directory
setwd("C:/Users/rshuell/Desktop/input_files")

# Get a list of all the files in the directory
file_list <- list.files()

# Start merging the files in the directory into a single dataframe
for (file in file_list){
  # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
  if (!exists("dataset")){
    dataset <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
  }
  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
  if (exists("dataset")){
    temp_dataset <-read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
    dataset<-rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }
}
```

Then, pick out the columns you want.

library(dplyr)

```
df1 %>%
  select(X, Y, Z)

Or ....

select(df1, X, Y, Z)
```

Finally, save your dataframe to a CSV file.

```
write.csv(df,'C:\\your_path\\new_file.csv')
```